# Reset button using JavaScript is not working after validating the form using Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, validation

I have a "create user"form with reset and create button. This reset button is not working for some drop-downs in the form.

In addition, reset button is not clearing all the values in the form after validation. It only clears the values entered after validation.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="form-action clearfix">
<button type="button" onClick="clearForm()" > Reset </button>
<button class="button" type="button" id="button"       onclick="doAjax('index.php/users/createUser', convertFormJson('#createUserForm'));">Create</button>
```

and

```
function clearForm() {
document.getElementById('createUserForm').reset(); 
}
```

Form:

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
            <div class="container_12 clearfix leading" >
                <div class="grid_12">

                        <!--<form class=    "form has-validation">-->
                        <?php 

                            $attributes = array('class' => 'form has-validation', 'id' => 'createUserForm');
                            echo form_open('/users/createUser', $attributes); 

                        ?>
                        <div class="clearfix">
                            <label for="form-name" class="form-label">First Name <em>*</em></label>
                            <div class="form-input">
                                <input type="text" id="form-name" name="firstname" required="required" placeholder="Enter the first name" value="<?php echo set_value('firstname'); ?>" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="clearfix">
                            <label for="form-name" class="form-label">Last Name <em>*</em></label>
                            <div class="form-input">
                                <input type="text" id="form-name" name="lastname" required="required" placeholder="Enter the last name" value="<?php echo set_value('lastname'); ?>"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="clearfix">
                            <label for="form-email" class="form-label">Email <em>*</em></label>
                            <div class="form-input"><input type="email" id="form-email" name="email" required="required" placeholder="A valid email address" value="<?php echo set_value('email'); ?>"/></div>
                        </div>

                        <!--
                        <div class="clearfix">
                            <label for="form-birthday" class="form-label">Birthdate</label>
                            <div class="form-input"><input type="date"  id="form-birthday" name="date" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" value="<?php //echo set_value('date'); ?>" class="date"/></div>
                        </div>
                        -->

                            <div class="clearfix">
                            <label for="form-username" class="form-label">Username <em>*</em></label>
                            <div class="form-input">
                                <?php echo form_error('username'); ?>
                                <input type="text" id="form-username" name="username" value="<?php echo set_value('username'); ?>" required="required" maxlength="30" placeholder="Alphanumeric (max 30 char.)" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="clearfix">
                            <label for="form-password" class="form-label">Password <em>*</em></label>
                            <div class="form-input">
                                <?php echo form_error('password'); ?>
                                <input type="password" id="form-password" name="password" value="<?php echo set_value('password'); ?>" maxlength="30" placeholder="Min 8 char. containing a capital, number and/or symbol" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="clearfix">
                            <label for="form-password-check" class="form-label">Password check <em>*</em></label>
                            <div class="form-input">
                                <?php echo form_error('passconf'); ?>
                                <input type="password" id="form-password-check" name="passconf" value="<?php echo set_value('passconf'); ?>" data-equals="password" maxlength="30" placeholder="Re-enter your password" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="clearfix">
                            <label for="form-group" class="form-label">Group <em>*</em></label>
                            <div class="form-input">
                                <?php 
                                        $groupsData[' '] = "--";
                                        $groupJs = 'id="form-group"';
                                        echo form_dropdown('groupId', $groupsData,' ',$groupJs);
                                    ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="clearfix">
                            <label for="form-language" class="form-label" >Language <em>*</em></label>
                            <div class="form-input">
                                <select id="form-language" name="language">
                                    <option value ="" > -- </option>
                                    <option value ="1">English</option>
                                    <option value ="2">French</option>    
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="clearfix">
                            <label for="form-timezone" class="form-label"  >Timezone <em>*</em></label>
                            <div class="form-input">
                                <?php echo timezone_menu('UM5', 'form-timezone'); ?>
                             </div>
                        </div>
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Any Javascript error in your console?

Comment: off topic, but I've never understood why people use "clear form" buttons. What's the point? Who has ever filled out a form then decided, nope, that's not what I wanted to do and clicked the clear form button??

Comment: Where is the form? (offtopic: is a button without class button no button?)

Comment: @Andreas: Pls find the form code.

Comment: Not the problem here, but id's have to be unique. You're using `form-name` twice. Is this `$groupsData[' '] = "--";` really working?

Comment: Yes, $groupsData[' '] = "--"; it works. I have changed the id name now. Still no positive result.

Comment: Any reason you aren't wrapping the elements in a `<form>` object and using the `<input type="reset"/>` button?

Comment: @normmcgarry: I tried using <input type="reset"/> button. But it doesn't work.

Comment: I see you're using `echo form_open('/users/createUser', $attributes);` - I am guessing that is from CodeIgniter, judging by a quick Google. are you doing a `echo form_close();` at the end to close the form? That would most likely be your problem, if not.

Comment: @normmcgarry: yes I am using CodeIgniter. Now I closed the form, but it doesn't solve.

Comment: Now that you've closed the form, does `<input type="reset"/>` work?

Comment: @normmcgarry: No. Finally I have used jquery and it worked. Thanks!